# IHtmlContent WriteTo invokes after parent component dispose

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am trying to develop a fluent framework for bootstrap (https://github.com/burcinsahin/FluentBootstrapCore) and I have an example usage as below.

```
@using (Html.Bootstrap().Form().Begin())
{
    @Html.Bootstrap().Input()
}
```

Here container form dispose is invoked before Input WriteTo method. Input is some class extends.NetCore Built-in IHtmlContent interface.
Begin writes to HtmlHelper ViewContext to manually and after dispose it ends the tag in the same way. Here the html output written to page is correct and I do not have any problem there.

```
    public class ComponentBuilder<TComponent> : IDisposable
        where TComponent : SingleComponent
    {
        protected readonly IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;
        protected readonly TComponent _component;

        internal IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper => _htmlHelper;
        internal TComponent Component => _component;

        public ComponentBuilder(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, TComponent component)
        {
            _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
            _component = component;
            _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(_component.Begin());
            _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(_component.Body());
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"ComponentBuilder.Dispose for {typeof(TComponent).Name} invoked.");
            _htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(_component.End());
        }
    }
```

```
public class BootstrapContent<TComponent> : IHtmlContent
        where TComponent : SingleComponent
    {
        private readonly TComponent _component;
        private readonly IHtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

        internal TComponent Component => _component;
        internal IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper => _htmlHelper;

        public BootstrapContent(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, TComponent component)
        {
            _htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
            _component = component;
        }

        public void WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"BootstrapContent.WriteTo for {typeof(TComponent).Name} invoked.");
            var html = _component.ToHtml();
            writer.Write(html);
        }

        public ComponentBuilder<TComponent> Begin()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"BootstrapContent.Begin for {typeof(TComponent).Name} invoked.");
            return new ComponentBuilder<TComponent>(_htmlHelper, _component);
        }
    }
```

Problem is: I have a stack for components and because of this interesting order of invokes, I can not push or pop the stack in the correct order. Parent is disposed and empties the stack then the component inside starts its operations and finds an empty stack when needed.

Output is as below:

```
BootstrapContent.Begin for Form invoked.
ComponentBuilder.Dispose for Form invoked.
BootstrapContent.WriteTo for Input invoked.
```

Here is the call stack (ExternalCode) where WriteTo method invoked:
[image: screencaptured]

Note: I use .Net (Core) 6 for application layer and .NetStandart 2.1 for class libraries, when I changed all them to .Net (Core) 7 it still behaves in the same way. I have created a branch named "issue/dispose" for anyone who wants to review this issue.

So, this problem seems as a big issue for me. Anyone who knows why the dispose method is invoked before the component inside the "using" scope. Or any other suggestions to try?

Note: After a while I will write this issue directly to Microsoft. I want to make sure that there is not any point I missed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your relevant code snippet? How did you found that its has been invoked after parent component?

Comment: Hi, I can see it by debugging with breakpoints or using Debug.Writeline(...) method. https://github.com/burcinsahin/FluentBootstrapCore repository, "issue/dispose" branch has UnitTest.cshtml. I set it as launchUrl and added Debug.Writeline calls to related methods.